# Filter works on last selection but no others

Tags: functions, filters, advanced-custom-fields

I have been working on a frontend filter using ACF Custom Fields. I can filter by the last selection states. but can't select any other option. Below is my code any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am thinking the problem is in here. If you need more info please let me know. Thanks in advance.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'ransom_filter_function'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'ransom_filter_function');

function ransom_filter_function(){
    $s        = $_POST['s'];
    $iperson = $_POST['iperson'];
    $country  = $_POST['country'];
    $state    = $_POST['state'];

$args = array (
    'post_type'      => 'myposttype',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    's'              => $s,
);

// Inperson Virtual Checkbox
if( isset( $iperson ) && !empty( $iperson ) )
    $args['meta_query'] = array(
        array (
            'key' => 'iperson_virtual',
            'value' => '"'.$iperson.'"',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
    );

// Country Dropdown
if( isset( $country ) && $country )
    $args['meta_query'] = array(
        array (
            'value' => $country,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
    );
    
// State Dropdown
if( isset( $state ) && $state )
   $args['meta_query'] = array(
        array (
          'value' => $_POST['state'],
          'compare' => '='
        ),
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Form page call

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">
    <label>
        <input type="text" name='s'>
    </label>

    <!-- Inperson Checkbox -->
    <?php
    if( have_rows('basic_info') ){
        // Loop through rows.
        while( have_rows('basic_info') ) { the_row();
            $ipvs = get_sub_field( 'inperson' );
            $field = get_field_object('field_60457a3f8f347');
            $choices = $field['choices'];
    ?>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach( $choices as $choice => $label ) : ?>
                <input type="checkbox" name="iperson" id="ipvfilter" value="<?php echo $choice; ?>" /><?php echo $label; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>

     <!-- Country Select -->
    <?php
    if( have_rows('basic_info') ){
        // Loop through rows.
        while( have_rows('basic_info') ) { the_row();
            $race_country = get_sub_field( 'country' );
            $country_field = get_field_object('field_60457b018f348');
            $countries = $country_field['choices'];
    ?>
            <select id="country" name="country" class="country">
                <option>Select Country</option>
                <?php foreach( $countries as $country => $label ) : ?>
                    <option name="country" id="country" value="<?php echo $country; ?>"><?php echo $label; ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>

     <!-- State Select -->
    <?php if( have_rows('basic_info') ){
        // Loop through rows.
        while( have_rows('basic_info') ) { the_row();
            $race_state = get_sub_field( 'state' );
            $state_field = get_field_object('field_60457b4d8f349');
            $states = $state_field['choices'];
        ?>

            <select id="state" name="state" class="state">
                <option>Select State</option>
                <?php foreach( $states as $state => $label ) : ?>
                    <option name="state" id="state" value="<?php echo $state; ?>" ><?php echo $label; ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>


    <button>Apply filter</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="myfilter">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want people to be able to add multiple filters but the code above is only allowing one filter to be used at a time. If this assumption is true, you'll need to update your code to *add to* the `meta_query` array rather than replace it in each conditional block. For example.

```php
function ransom_filter_function() {
    $s          = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['s'] );
    $iperson    = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['iperson'] );
    $country    = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['country'] );
    $state      = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['state'] );
    $args       = array(
        'post_type'      => 'myposttype',
        'posts_per_page' => - 1,
        's'              => $s,
    );
    $meta_query = array();

    // Inperson Virtual Checkbox
    if ( isset( $iperson ) && ! empty( $iperson ) ) {
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'     => 'iperson_virtual',
            'value'   => '"' . $iperson . '"',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        );
    }

    // Country Dropdown
    if ( isset( $country ) && $country ) {
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'value'   => $country,
            'compare' => '='
        );
    }

    // State Dropdown
    if ( isset( $state ) && $state ) {
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'value'   => $state,
            'compare' => '='
        );
    }

    if ( ! empty( $meta_query ) ) {
        $args['meta_query'] = $meta_query;
    }

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
}
```

An aside to the above, you should always [sanitize user input](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-validation/) and then [validate the data](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-validation/) you have is expected before using it. I've used `sanitize_text_field()` as an example.

Comment: Thank you, I will test this afternoon and get back to you.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the help, I added in the suggestions you wrote above to no avail. sanatize_text_field() good call. It is still only filtering by the last field selected and when I try any others by themself I get my else call "No posts found."  I will add the form code below if that will help. Thanks for the help been trying to get this working for a few days now.

Comment: With multiple meta queries, the default `relationship` is `AND` which makes the query more specific. The other option is `OR` which might be what you're expecting.

Comment: I am just trying to select an option from the inperson checkbox and it gives me no results. The only one I get results from is if I select the last select box on the page  <!-- State Select -->. Any thoughts as to why that would be happening?